# How to use an object as a key in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to use a custom object as a key in a hash-like structure. I've tried using `NS[Mutable]Dictionary` but in order for my object to be a key it has to implement the `NSCopying` protocol. `NSDictionary` is sending a `copy` message to all of it's keys as far as I've read. I don't want to implement the protocol (my object is quite complex) nor do I want it to be copied. What are my options? Do I have any?

Comment: The obvious alternative is to not use a custom object as the key. Isn't there some string or number that could be used to identify it uniquely?

Comment: I was asking for an alternative to allow me to use the object as key without an useless copy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDictionary` is toll-free bridged with `CFDictionaryRef`, but they actually differ in behavior when adding objects. Specifically, `NSDictionary`'s `-setObject:forKey:` will copy the key, but `CFDictionaryRef`'s `CFDictionarySetValue()` will *not* copy the key. This means that if you want to use non-copyable keys, you can use `CFDictionarySetValue()` instead to add it to the dictionary.

```
CFDictionarySetValue((CFMutableDictionaryRef)myDict, myKey, myValue);
```

This will still retain the key, but it won't copy it. And you can use the normal `NSDictionary` methods for everything else.

Comment: You can also be tricksy and have `copy` just return `[self retain]`, but that obviously breaks semantics.

Comment: this is what I've been looking for, I have nothing against retaining my object, it makes sense, but copying is a bit to much. I wonder why did they choose to copy the key in the NSDictionary version...

Comment: @ValentinRadu -- They copy the key because otherwise, if you subsequently modified the key, you'd corrupt the dictionary.  If you use a scheme that does not involve a copy you must never modify the fields that are hashed while the key object is in the dictionary.

Comment: @HotLicks So basically I'm not allowed to change the key object because the hash changes and the key will not be found? That's quite a limitation, I think. I might have to think this over.

Comment: @ValentinRadu -- Yes, inside the dictionary is a hash table, and the hash table is consulted as the first step in the search.  If you alter the key so it's hash is changed (but don't remove/insert it to "fix" things), the hash table will select the wrong synonym chain and your object will not be found.  Of course, you control the hash algorithm and can (at the cost of poorer performance) omit hashing "volatile" parts of the key fields.  (This is one reason why it might be wise to roll your own, just once -- to become familiar with the internal concepts involved.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the `NSDictionary` to retain the object? If not, you can turn it into an `NSValue` and use that as the key:

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:yourCustomObject];
[dictionary setObject:someObject forKey:value];
```

This can get a bit messy but is in alternative to implementing `NSCopying`.

Comment: If the dictionary is the only reference to the object then it'll die.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own dictionary.  Not really that hard.

Another option is to use a surrogate object, containing a pointer to "the" object.  The surrogate would implement the hash and either copy or reference the fields to be compared for isEqual.  It could do a basic sanity check to assure the compared fields have not been changed when it's referenced.

Comment: Harder than using an existing dictionary though, i.e. `CFDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self retain];
}
```

Comment: Unless your object is immutable, that's a rather bad idea.

Comment: It only has to be immutable with respect to the `hash` and `isEqual:` messages.  By default those just use the object pointer.

Comment: What do you mean, only has to be? If it's mutable *in any fashion* then exposing a `-copy` method that skips the actual copying is a *really bad idea*. It means code that looks like `Klass newobj = [obj copy]; [newobj mutateSomeProperty];` will actually modify the original `obj`, which violates every expectation of what `-copy` means.

Comment: He said he doesn't want to implement `copy` at all.  So presumably he's being careful not to use APIs that demand a `copy` that works.  Therefore he can do whatever he wants with it.

Comment: The act of implementing copy is a public declaration that says "I support copying". Trying to secretly implement copy in a manner that violates all expectations of how copy works is a really bad idea, because it's impossible to keep the knowledge of that implementation a secret forever (yay dynamic runtimes), and once that's exposed outside of the class, people will make the assumption that `-copy` really does copy the object.